# How to load file from computer OR from URL

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

I have an webapp, that takes JSON file and parses it into objects. My goal is to make an user capable of uploading a file from their local computer or from a URL.

My index JSP page looks like this:

```
<form method="post" action="products" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select a file from the computer <input type="file" name="file">
    <br>
    Or load from URL<input type="url" name="urlFile">
    <br>
<button type="submit">Parse</button>
```

The controller class looks like this

```
public String parse(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                    @RequestParam("urlFile") URL url,
                     Model model)
                     throws IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException
{
    File convFile = null;

    if(file != null)
    {
        convFile = new File(file.getOriginalFilename());
        file.transferTo(convFile);
    }
    else if(url != null)
    {
        String tDir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
        String path = tDir + "tmp" + ".xml";
        convFile = new File(path);
        convFile.deleteOnExit(); 
        FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, convFile);
    }

    //... parsing JSON...
    return "products"
}
```

When I try to upload it from local computer it works so well, but when I try to do it with URL I get 500 Error (`java.io.FileNotFoundException`). I believe it's because the system still tries to find it like a local file on computer. How can I solve it?

Comment: 1. Read, and post, the stack trace of the exception. 2. Use your debugger, or simple System.out.println to know what your variables contain. 3. Learn how to create a file path correctly: new File(dir, name) (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/nio/file/Files.html). 4. Java has a method to create temporary files (not sure what the point of saving to a temp file, however): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempFile-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-

Answer (score 2):

The exception is coming from `FileUtils.copyURLToFile`. [The JavaDoc for this method](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyURLToFile(java.net.URL,%20java.io.File)) says this can occur for the following reasons:

> 1. If source URL cannot be opened
> 2. If destination is a directory
> 3. If destination cannot be written
> 4. If destination needs creating but can't be
> 5. If an IO error occurs during copying

I reckon the two most likely candidates are #3 and #4. You probably don't have access to write to that directory. Add a try-catch around the FileUtils method and log the problem.

```
String tDir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
String path = tDir + "tmp" + ".xml";
convFile = new File(path);
convFile.deleteOnExit();
try {
    FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, convFile);
}
catch (IOException e) {
    // log exception
}
```

Comment: Given that the OP is working in a web framework, it would be better to add logging to whatever hook the framework itself provides for error handling. The best place to log failures is usually at (or slightly above in the case of frameworks) the boundary of your code. Putting it directly around the call might result in an incorrectly swallowed error because the rethrow may be forgotten, and with a rethrow, it could result in duplicated logging.